# How to set up writing to html table from .json file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, webpack

I need to write a code like this that will fill the table from the specified folder (tracks) containing only .json files like:

```
{
            "EndTime": "11:00",
            "Person": [
                {
                    "name": "one",
                    "age": 5
                },
                {
                    "name": "two",
                    "age": 7
                }
            ],
            "StartTime": "10:45"
        }
```

I'm a beginner, I don't understand how to append rows to a table, taking data from .json files
html.file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MUI Landing Page Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-latest/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Measurements</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-latest/js/mui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="mui-appbar mui--z1">
      <div class="mui-container">
        <table>
          <tr class="mui--appbar-height">
            <td class="mui--text-title">Measurements</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="mui--text-center">
      <div class="mui--appbar-height"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="mui--text-display3">Measurements</div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button 
        type = "submit"
        id = "submit"
        class="mui-btn mui-btn--primary"
        >
        take info
    </button>
    </div>
    <table class="mui-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Name of file</th>
            <th>Start time</th>
            <th>End time</th>
            <th>Nuber of person</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody id='myTable'>
      </table>
    <footer>
      <div class="mui-container mui--text-center">
        Made by Kumiho
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output : {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000
    },
    plugins: [
new HTMLPlugin({
template: './src/index.html'
}),
new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      }
}
```

app.js

```
import './static/styles.css'

const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function(){
        const tr = [{
            "EndTime": "11:00",
            "Person": [
                {
                    "name": "one",
                    "age": 5
                },
                {
                    "name": "two",
                    "age": 7
                }
            ],
            "StartTime": "10:45"
        },
        {
            "EndTime": "11:05",
            "Person": [
                {
                    "name": "three",
                    "age": 6
                },
                {
                    "name": "four",
                    "age": 7
                }
            ],
            "StartTime": "11:00"
        }]
document.querySelector('.content').insertRow= `<table class="track"></table>`


   for (let i=0; i< tr.length; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('TR');
    let td = document.createElement('TD');
    document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function(){

    let row = document.createElement ('str')
    row.insertRow = '<tr>' +
                  `<td>+${index}+</td>` +
                  `<td>+${file}+</td>` +
                  `<td>+${tr.StartTime}+</td>` +
                  `<td>+${tr.EndTime}+</td>` +
                  `<td>+${tr.Person.length}+</td>` +
                '</tr>';
   
   document.querySelector('.track').appendChild(row)
    
}
}
```

The site starts, but gives an error:

> app.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'insertRow')at HTMLButtonElement.document.querySelector.onclick

besides, as you can see, the table is not filled even with a given array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues.

Here is a working version - I will list SOME of the issues

1. NEVER call anything submit. If in a form, the submit event will be hidden if you do
2. You are not using the template literals efficiently. Do not concatenate template literals - it is a waste of literals
3. You want to fill a table but you try to set the insertRow attribute of content
4. What is `let row = document.createElement ('str')` supposed to do? `<str>` is not a known HTML tag

I did not look at the other code - ask more questions

```js
const rows = [{
    "EndTime": "11:00",
    "Person": [{
        "name": "one",
        "age": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "two",
        "age": 7
      }
    ],
    "StartTime": "10:45"
  },
  {
    "EndTime": "11:05",
    "Person": [{
        "name": "three",
        "age": 6
      },
      {
        "name": "four",
        "age": 7
      }
    ],
    "StartTime": "11:00"
  }
]

const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
document.getElementById("subBut").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  table.innerHTML = rows.map((tr, index) => `<tr><td>${index}</td>
          <td>${tr.StartTime}</td>
          <td>${tr.EndTime}</td>
          <td>${tr.Person.length}</td>
          </tr>`).join("")
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable" class="track"></tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="subBut" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and for your work. now the mistake is
> app.js: 31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
Please help me solve this.